# How to replace unicode character in file?

Tags: linux, unicode

I'm reading one file using java and using "\u0001" as a field separator.
This file is present in linux machine.

But when I do `head filename`, I can't see "\u0001" as field separator in file. May I know please how can I see the field separator in file on terminal ? How to replace "\u0001" with something else on terminal ?

Comment: What encoding is the file using? Utf-8?

Comment: @Shawn, yes its UTF-8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to use a different character when displaying the file to make it more human readable:

```sh
tr $'\u0001' ',' < thefile.txt
```

(Assuming you're using `bash` or another shell that supports [`$'string'` style escapes](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/ANSI_002dC-Quoting.html))

Comment: Cool..! Can you please share how its working ? dont know about tr

Comment: @FreshTransistor `tr` **tr**anslates one set of characters to another. In the case it converts the field separators from 1 bytes to commas. (`$'\001'` and `$'\x01'` are other ways of writing it).

Answer (score 0):

Does this help?:

```
`cat -A filename|head`
```

cat `-A` shows all characters, bu even though you can see these `invisible` characters, I am not sure how you will go about separating those in the console.. or using such a character as a separator on a plain console..

Comment: Thx I can see the special character now which is ^A, but how can I replace this on console ?

Comment: That is what I mentioned in my answer.. you will have hard time writing out or representing those invisible characters in plain console... I would look into how to read this file in Python or some other Programming language, which has already libraries to parse such characters.. I would also say that if you are parsing a non-text file, but a Binary file? you are going the wrong way trying to read a non-text file as text.. which would always cause issues..